# Generalization of the Triangle Inequality with Sets

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

**Definition**: The distance between two points $p_1, p_2 \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is
\begin{equation}
     d(p_1,p_2)=|| p_1-p_2 ||.
\end{equation}
The distance between a point $p\in \mathbb{R}^n$ and a set $\mathcal{C} \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is
\begin{equation}
    d(p,\mathcal{C}) = \inf\{||p-q|| : q \in \mathcal{C}\}.
\end{equation}

Given three points $p_i \in \mathbb{R}^n, i=1,2,3$. The triangle inequality tells us that 
\begin{equation}
     |d(p_1,p_3) - d(p_3,p_2)|  \le d(p_1, p_2) \le d(p_1, p_3) + d(p_3,p_2).
\end{equation}

Now the problem is:

Is the triangle inequality still held if **one point** is replaced by a non-singleton set?

Comment: Suppose part 3 held true. Do you see that you get parts 1 and 2 from here by taking some sets as singletons? Try to work therefore with three sets at first(I am not telling you if it's true or not, only that if it were true life is easier).

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг how about the edits? (non-singleton sets?)

Comment: You have edited the question. Is this how it will finally stand?

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг I try to simplify the problem first. I know that the right part of the inequality is not correct because if this set contains the two points, then $d(p_1,p_2) \ge 0$ (assume that $p_3$ is replaced by a non-singleton set).

Comment: Correct. So, for example, if we take a set $P$ with at least two points, and $p_1 \neq p_2$ in $P$, then $d(p_1,p_2) > 0$ although $d(p_1,P)$ and $d(p_2,P)$ are both zero. However, if we replace $p_1$ by a set $P$, then does the right side of the inequality work? We will figure the left side later.